# Adding data-toggle & data-target breaks Nav links

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

My navbar works, but I'd like it to auto collapse when a link is clicked. To do this, I understand I have to add `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"` to each link in the html. Unfortunately, this breaks the link, it does collapse but it won't scroll to its target anymore on click. What am I not seeing?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Studio</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#title_page">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#info">Information</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#program_mobile" id="navlink_lessson_program">Program</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you can check this [Bootstrap JS Collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp) on the same.

Comment: @ArifMustafa That doesn't seem to mention why the link would break?

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have answered my own question. The data-toggle and data-target attributes just don't work well within an  link, so I place a `<span>` inside the link with those attributes, and now it works as intended.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Modern Piano Studio</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#title_page"><span data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">Home</span><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#info"><span data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">Information</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#program_mobile" id="navlink_lessson_program"><span data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">Lesson Program</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#testimonials"><span data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">Testimonials</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#contact"><span data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">Contact</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Good solution, putting the data attribute in a link tag (also works for Bootstrap 5). The reason putting the attributes in the `<a>` tag didn't work is because Bootstrap support actions associated with buttons or other clickable elements. Anchors are clickable, but they're intended to navigate to a different place. If the tag is an ['A' or 'AREA' tag](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/d0cc42c009c2f680e2fdfd3df4cf06b90d0bfd09/js/src/util/component-functions.js#L17), Bootstrap prevents the default action.